# Google map api loading but not showing the map on FF / Chrome (recently), ok on Safari and iOs

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Google map api is loading (showing pins, zoom in/out buttons) but not showing the map on FF / Chrome since few days : http://www.bellastock.com/preview/contact/

ok on Safari and iOs (iPhone & iPad)

not ok on pc - Chrome / FF / IE (logic)

When i'm tracking the image loaded, the map images are well loaded but never affected.

I try loading api in http & https with the same issue, ex :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

in same time, it seems there is a problem with button sprites on all browser (zoom in/out, google street view)

The strange thing is that i use approximatively the same code as an older project which not have this issue : http://www.letrot.com/nocturnes-hippodrome-vincennes/infos-pratiques.php

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your css (row 2119)

```
.content .row-content .post-content img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If you comment max-width all works fine.

Comment: ok I understant the problem but never search in this direction. Thanks for all, it's fixed !!